# Good practices for sharing files between virtual machines (Xen)?

Tags: networking, virtualization, xen, share

I have a remote Xen server running some virtual machines and i want to share some files between them. Can you recommend a good pratice doing this ?

Currently network setup is the standard Xen networking (bridging), each VM has an eth interface with dedicated public IP. I'm thinking of adding a bridge for private networking in dom0, but not sure what to do from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking to from network storages like SAN or NAS then you can use for both guest using NFS in fstab file of both server you can give enter y auto,_netdev, and in export file 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(ro,no_root_squash,sync).

Answer (score 3):

NFS is a good way to share data between Linux/Unix systems. or use samba to share file via linux and windows. But remember to secure the share.

Answer (score 1):

Share an NFS or SMB volume (depending on what O/S you're running on the VMs) from a server - which could be one of the VMs if necessary.  Then have the VMs mount the volume and read/write files to it.